# free space under table inside pre

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got such `div` tag.

```
<div class="col-md-11" style="margin-left: -55px; width: 94%;">
     <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <pre id="data" class="prettyprint">
          </pre>
     </div>
</div>
```

I insert table inside `<pre>` using `javascript`

```
function createUserData() {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = 
            '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">' +
                '<tr>' + 
                      '<td>User name: </td><td>${user.name}</td>' + 
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' + 
                      '<td>Email: </td><td>${user.emailAddress}</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                       '<td>Organization: </td><td>${user.organization}</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' + 
                       '<td>Certificate: </td><td>${user.certificate}</td>' +
                '</tr>' + 
             '</table>';
    }
```

But it adds clean line or something like this under the table. How to get rid of it?
As for table - I use `twitter bootstrap 3` to style it.

[image]

Comment: Use Chrome's dev tools to see if it's margin or padding that belongs to one of the elements and then set that value to 0.

Comment: I see. It was table - it had `margin-bottom: 20px`. I changed it to `0px;` and it works fine.

Comment: See also the "answer" below, which is really a comment.  You're putting stuff in a pre that doesn't belong.

Comment: How is it a comment @MichaelChaney?  The first diagnostic step to fixing any position/related/css issues is to validate the code. This code does not validate because it contains improperly nested tags.  thus, the answer is to use valid HTML to get expected layout.

Comment: He can follow your advice and he still wouldn't get the desired layout because the table has a margin-bottom of 20px.  The fact that it's inside a pre isn't germane to the question - he could move the table to a div or whatever and it would still have that margin at the bottom.  Therefore, your "answer" doesn't answer his question in any way - it's simply a *comment* about his HTML being incorrect.  Hopefully you see the difference.  I would also note that it's not an "odd thing" as bootstrap adds the 20px bottom margin to tables - it's fully expected.

Answer (score 0):

a `pre` tag should only contain `phrasing content`, of which a `table` is Not.

```
 Line 6, Column 12: Element table not allowed as child of element pre in this context. 
<pre><table><tr><td>hi</td></tr></table></pre>
Contexts in which element table may be used:
Where flow content is expected.
Content model for element pre:
 Phrasing content.
```

read more about content categories.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content

Because you have invalid html, odd things will happen.